# Wordpress redirection

Tags: htaccess, apache

I tried to import my Wordpress website, localy on a RHEL OS.

Finally, 80% f the pages seems to be OK and are displaied except 20% of them.. I've noticed that it depends on the URL format

```
https://site1.example.net/?page_id=271  -> Wordpress Post  -> fine ! OK
https://site1.example.net/?product=memory-card  -> Wocommerce  Product -> fine.
```

but the URL like

```
https://site1.example.net/discontinued/discontinued_product/
```

are not displayed properly?!!?

So, I've had a look on the .htaccess file.. and I have :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(ftp.*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^bridge2cart/(.*\.php)$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^rewrite\.html$ /rewrite.php [L]
#
```

The same as the original one..

and my apache config :

```
<Directory "/home/example/">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    #        Order allow,deny
    #        allow from all   
</Directory>
```

I cannot see why

any idea ?

Thanks and regards,

Comment: What do you mean by "not displayed properly?!!?"? The key difference between those URLs is that the URL that is _not_ working is dependent on mod_rewrite (.htaccess`), whereas the URLs that are working do not use mod_rewrite at all. But if mod-rewrite/`.htaccess` was not working at all then that non-working URL would result in a 404. What about the vHost config? (You are presumably using a vHost?) The document root is presumably `/home/example`?

Comment: Hi,In fact the  the vHost is my own server, running Rocky 8 - With the .htaccess that I have, going to the link : https://site1.example.net/discontinued/discontinued_product/ the website is going to the homepage  ??!!?? - What I tent to do, is to built a staging website in order to make some tests.. - For pages, post and products... that works... - Pls have a look on https://site1.aztgrp.net  -then try https://site1.aztgrp.net/discontinued/discontinued_siemens/

Comment: Those URLs appear to be working OK for me? Have you fixed this? What did you change?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.. that works out.. Yesterday I found that I needed to change **again**, the Permanent link..
I had to change it when I've copied the site on my local server..and I lost these "folder" link. I came back with " Post name" settings ( as it was before )... and that works out

I am not sure to understand, why I had to change from "post name" ->  "Plain" and come back to "Post name".. but that's OK now :-)
Thanks for your help